# How to add an APA-style citation with no author in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, context, apa-style, context-mkiv

I need to cite some articles which were created by some professional organizations, so no authors or editors are listed:

```
@Article{noname2012,
    author = {},
    title = {This is the title},
    publisher = {This is the publisher},
    year = {2012},
    address = {Miami}
}
```

I am using the APA style in ConTeXT, setup as follows:

```
\setupbibtex[database={Bibliography}, sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa]
```

Whenever I place a citation, `\cite{noname2012}` it displays like this:

```
(noname2012, 2012)
```

How can I the bibliography display the title instead of the name, when the name and editor fields are empty?

Comment: You mention that the publications were produced by organizations. Could you list the organizations as "corporate" authors? E.g., `author = "{Securities and Exchange Commission}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimum working example. It's a slight compromise because it requires you to add the title to your .tex file.

```
\setupbibtex[database={Bibliography}, sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa]

\def\citeTitle{\dosingleempty\dociteTitle}
\def\dociteTitle[#1]#2{%
 \iffirstargument\cite[inbetween=,left={(#1,\ },right=)][#2]\else
 \cite[inbetween=,left=(,right=)][#2]\fi}

\starttext

The Bib\TeX\ file needs to have the nameless author as a nested pair of
empty braces.
\starttyping
@Article{noname2012,
    author = {{}},
    title = {This is the title},
    publisher = {This is the publisher},
    year = {2012},
    address = {Miami}
}
\stoptyping

Now, whenever I place a citation, \type{\cite{noname2012}} it displays like
this: \cite{noname2012} which is still unsatisfactory.  If I add an
optional argument and put the label in square brackets,

\type{\cite[inbetween=][noname2012]}

it displays like this: \cite[inbetween=][noname2012]. Still not quite
right, but I can add the title manually,

\type{\cite[inbetween=,left={(This is the title,\ }][noname2012]}

so that it displays like this:
\cite[inbetween=,left={(This is the title,\ }][noname2012].

With the user||defined command \type{\citeTitle}, it looks like this
\citeTitle{noname2012} or like this
\citeTitle[This is the title]{noname2012}

\stoptext
```

Comment: The following answer may also be relevant: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352688/31316)

Answer (score 1):

For the citations, it's possible to define a new option for cases where you know there is no author:

```
% Define a new type of APA citation for title
\definebtx[apa:cite:noauthor][apa:cite:authoryear]
\startsetups btx:apa:cite:noauthor
    \btxcitereference
    \quotation{\btxflush{title}}
    \btxcomma
    \btxflush{year}
\stopsetups
```

So instead of `\cite[noname2012]`, you would use `\cite[noauthor][noname2012]`. This solution is based on the example on page 52 of the [publications manual](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf).

As for the bibliography, you'd probably have to overwrite the basic article definition. For the following, I copy and pasted the standard definition from the [source](http://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-apa.mkvi) and added a switch to test if there is no author:

```
% Define a switch in bibliography entry
\startsetups btx:apa:list:article
    \doiftextelse{\btxdirect{author}} {
        \texdefinition{btx:apa:authoryear}
        \texdefinition{btx:apa:title-if-not-placed}
    } {
        %If no author, use title as first entry
        \btxflush{title}
        \btxperiod
        \btxleftparenthesis
        \btxflush{year}
        \btxrightparenthesis
        \btxperiod
    }
    \btxdoif {type} {
        \btxleftbracket
        \btxflush{type}
        \btxrightbracketperiod
    }
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:journal-volume-number-pages}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:url-doi-note}
\stopsetups
```

If needed, a similar switch could be used in the citation to automatically handle the author/noauthor cases.

Combined together with demonstration:

```
\startbuffer[ref]
@article{solo,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {Title with author},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2000},
  month = {1},
  volume = {1}
}

@article{none,
  author = {},
  title = {Title with no author},
  journal = {Journal},
  month = {1},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {1}
}
\stopbuffer

% Boilerplate to set up references
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdataset[ref][ref.buffer]
\setupbtx[dataset=ref]

\definebtxrendering[ref]
    [dataset=ref, 
     specification=apa]
\setupbtx[apa:cite]
    [alternative=authoryear,
     etallimit=1] 

% Define a new type of APA citation for title
\definebtx[apa:cite:noauthor][apa:cite:authoryear]
\startsetups btx:apa:cite:noauthor
    \btxcitereference
    \quotation{\btxflush{title}}
    \btxcomma
    \btxflush{year}
\stopsetups

% Define a switch in bibliography entry
\startsetups btx:apa:list:article
    \doiftextelse{\btxdirect{author}} {
        \texdefinition{btx:apa:authoryear}
        \texdefinition{btx:apa:title-if-not-placed}
    } {
        %If no author, use title as first entry
        \btxflush{title}
        \btxperiod
        \btxleftparenthesis
        \btxflush{year}
        \btxrightparenthesis
        \btxperiod
    }
    \btxdoif {type} {
        \btxleftbracket
        \btxflush{type}
        \btxrightbracketperiod
    }
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:journal-volume-number-pages}
    \texdefinition{btx:apa:url-doi-note}
\stopsetups

% Testing
\starttext

Normal citations: \cite[solo] vs. \cite[none] \\
Noauthor citations: \cite[noauthor][solo] vs. \cite[noauthor][none]

\startsubject[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[ref][method=dataset]
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

With the result:

[image]

However, as Mico suggested in the comments, it's easier to simply make the organization an author:

```
\startbuffer[ref]
@article{solo,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {Title with author},
  journal = {Journal},
  year = {2000},
  month = {1},
  volume = {1}
}

@article{none,
  author = {{Professional organization XYZ}},
  title = {Title with no author},
  journal = {Journal},
  month = {1},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {1}
}
\stopbuffer

% Boilerplate to set up references
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdataset[ref][ref.buffer]
\setupbtx[dataset=ref]

\definebtxrendering[ref]
    [dataset=ref, 
     specification=apa]
\setupbtx[apa:cite]
    [alternative=authoryear,
     etallimit=1] 

% Testing
\starttext

Normal citations: \cite[solo] vs. \cite[none] \\

\startsubject[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[ref][method=dataset]
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

With the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use the `natbib` package along with the `\bibliographystyle` defined as **apalike** or **newapa**.  Thus, your code will look like:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike} % or newapa, depending on what you are using
\bibliography{bibliography} % your bibliography.bib file
```

And then you can use either `\citep{authorlabel}` (for getting the whole reference in parenthesis) or `\citet{authorlabel}` (to get the year in parenthesis and the author outside of them).  I strongly recommend your to see Section 2.7 of the `natbib` [documentation](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) for more information on this.

Comment: Does that work in ConTeXt?