# Bibliography in Context \cite [authoryear] with no comma

Tags: bibliographies, context, apa-style

I am using APA in ConTeXt. Is there a way how to render authoryear with no comma between Author and Year, e.g. Author YYYY instead of Author, YYYY ?
Do I need to define a new citation style?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\setupbtx` to change the `inbetween`:

```
\setupbtx
[apa:cite:authoryear]
[inbetween={\btxspace\space}]
```

[image]